# how to use Windows Explorer search utility from vb.net

Tags: asp.net, search, windows-explorer

I would like to create a webpage that collects a users search criteria.  Then when they click a button, send the parameters to the Windows Explorer Search utility and run it.  Can this be done?  If so, how?  I am using asp.net to create my webpages.

Comment: do you want to run search on server machine or on client?

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Microsoft Windows Search 3.x SDK" at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=645300ae-5e7a-4ce7-95f0-49793f8f76e8&DisplayLang=en for more information. This will get you started. The SDK includes many samples in different languages.